# jQuery-implemented Calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, calculator

guys. I am trying to create a *web-based calculator* with basic operations using jQuery. I already have implemented the addition operation. Now, I am hooked in subtraction.

Here is a code snippet when you click on the minus button:

```
$("#btnSub").click(function () {
    holdValue = $("#result").val();
    currentValue = $("#result").val("0");

    flagSub = "1";
    flagNotEmpty = "0";
    flagDecimal = "0";
});
```

Here is a code snippet when you click the equals button:

```
$("#btnEquals").click(function () {
    if (flagNotEmpty == "0") {
        alert("Missing Value.");
    } else {
        if (flagAdd == "1") {
            currentValue = $("#result").val();
            var output = parseFloat(holdValue) + parseFloat(currentValue);
            $("#result").val(parseFloat(output));
        } else if (flagSub == "1") {
            currentValue = $("#result").val();
            var output2 = parseFloat(holdValue) - parseFloat(currentValue);
            $("#result").val(parseFloat(output2));
        }
    }

    flagSub = "0";
    flagAdd = "0";
    flagNotEmpty = "0";
    flagDecimal = "0";
});
```

Variables functions:

1. `flagSub`: used to determine that the operation choosen is subtraction
2. `flagNotEmpty`: used to determine if a number is pressed after selecting an operator. Displays error message if equal sign is clicked on right after the operator button.
3. `flagDecimal`: used to tell the program that a decimal has already been entered. Display error message for decimal point duplication.

Problem with this program is that it cannot perform subtraction when it is the first operation you do. That is, when the browser loads the UI and you do subtraction, nothing happens. BUT, when you do, for example, click `1 + 2 =` then the program displays `3` in the textbox. Without refreshing the page, click `- 10 =`. Difference is displayed.

To start from the beginning, please refresh the page; will just add the CLEAR button after I am done with all the operations.

Just want to know what is wrong with my algorithm. For the complete code with `html` and `css`, here is its [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vllnv/cQdVk/2/).

By the way, I have just started learning jQuery so please forgive me for the kind of messy and might be inefficient way of coding. Help is really much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flagAdd` needs to be initialized, you can alter the `btnSub` handler to do that

```
$("#btnSub").click(function () {
    holdValue = $("#result").val();
    currentValue = $("#result").val("0");

    flagAdd = "0";
    flagSub = "1";
    flagNotEmpty = "0";
    flagDecimal = "0";
});
```

alternatively you could initialize it in the document ready handler [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axrwkr/cQdVk/4/)